# Jmeter Perfmon plugin not showing any graph details

Tags: plugins, jmeter, perfmon

I have installed the JMeter Perfmon plugin, ensured port 4444 is open on my local host and target machines and started the agent on the target machine. When I start the test I can see the connection from Perfmon is established (no connection errors) but I do not get any graphical display - it just says waiting for samples. I have run longer tests that use a lot of CPU on the target machine but I still do not see any data.
Is there anything else that should be done aside from ensuring the ports(4444) are open and the server agent is started on the target machine to et the Perfom plugin to generate results (all my other plugins work ok)?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can check whether you can establish the connectivity with the [ServerAgent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent) by sending `test` command using TCP client application like [telnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet). If everything is correct you should see `Yep` response
2. Make sure to set IP address or hostname of the **target** machine in the PerfMon Metrics Collector listener, not localhost.
3. You need to properly place PerfMon Metrics Collector listener so it would be at least one Sampler in its [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules), if there will be no samplers you won't see any results there

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri, I am load testing an application from my local machine. JMeter is installed on the machine. Server Agent is up and running, and listening for TCP and UDP connections on port 4444 (the default port). But I am stuck at a level that I am not sure how to ensure connectivity with the ServerAgent which is also placed in my local machine in 'c' drive. Looking forward to your response. Thanks.